# Vagrant not loading the right versions

Tags: php, ansible, vagrant

After i updated my ansible playbooks php  version from 5 to 7.2 and xdebug to match the version.
and i run php -v in my vagrant box i get

> PHP 7.2.11-3+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2018 08:20:21) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.11-3+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans

but my `phpinfo();` says

> PHP Version 5.6.38-3+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 This program makes
>   use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend Engine v2.6.0,
>   Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans

My playbook

### ---

```
 name: Add ppa Repository
  sudo: yes
  apt_repository: repo=ppa:ondrej/{{ php.ppa }}

- name: Update apt
  sudo: yes
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: Install php72
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg=php7.2 state=latest

- name: Install php72-fpm
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg=php5-fpm state=latest

- name: Install PHP Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items: "{{php.packages}}"
  when: php.packages is defined

- name: Set date.timezone for CLI
  become: true
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    regexp: "date.timezone ="
    line: "date.timezone = Europe/Berlin"

- name: Set date.timezone for apache php
  become: true
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
    regexp: "date.timezone ="
    line: "date.timezone = Europe/Berlin"

- include: configure.yml
- include: pecl.yml
```

Comment: check php paths in both phpinfos, or type which php to find the one being used#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So doing `php -v` will tell you what version of php your php CLI is running on. Hence the conflicting versions in the CLI and phpinfo. Secondly, the 'pkg' on the task 'Install php72-fpm' is set to 'php5-fpm'; try switching that to the version you require and see how you get on.

Comment: I tried that but still does not work...im not sure if there is cache ? for vagrant ? or my other idea some root is being overriden ?

Comment: so I'm assuming that there wasn't an issue installing the new version of PHP? If not, did you try restarting the service? Depending on your system, this can be done in a number of ways. For Ubuntu it's `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart`

Comment: No i didnt have any problems install it just doesnt 'transfer' from my box to my local server. Restart didnt help

Comment: When you say 'doesn't transfer', do you mean that `phpinfo()` is still showing the wrong version?

Comment: Exactley. and even tho my vagrant box is showing the correct version.

Comment: Okay, so to start with let's remove the version of php that you don't want. In Ubuntu, it's `sudo apt remove php5-fpm`. Are you using Ubuntu? Next, try restarting apache, `sudo service apache2 restart`, this may or may not exist based on your current setup though. Check your phpinfo details once more, if that doesn't work restart the php7.2 service again and, fingers crossed, it should show you the correct version